# Custom Icon inside a <Tab> componen

Tags: material-ui

How can I use a custom Icon inside the '@material-ui/core/Tab' component ?

```
      <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          scrollButtons="on"
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary">
          <Tab label="Story" icon={ ???? public/icon/hammer.png" />} />
          <Tab label="Insperation" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />
     </Tabs>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Tab icon can be any node (https://material-ui.com/api/tab/#props). So you should be able to do `<Tab label="Story" icon={ <img src="public/icon/hammer.png" />} />`, you might have to style your image though.